# Is CompositeTransform used only in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

CompositeTransform is only used for silverlight?. Is there anyway we can use that in WPF or any equivalent replacement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no `CompositeTransform` in WPF however there is a `TransformGroup`.  Hence an equivalent replacement is a `TransformGroup` containing `ScaleTransform`, `SkewTransform`, `RotateTransform` and `TranslateTransform` in that order.

Comment: var Trans = (CompositeTransform)Btn_showDetail.RenderTransform;
            if (Trans.Rotation > 0)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Hide", true);
            }

Comment: do you think it would work if someone implements their own for WPF? (or decompile and use the one from Silverlight?)

Comment: How to get `TranslateTransform` values from `TransformGroup`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much nicer solution if you are anal about code cleanliness:

http://www.singulink.com/CodeIndex/post/getting-rid-of-ugly-transformgroup-blocks-in-wpf

Its easy on the eyes and because it just returns a TransformGroup, you can still use the Blend designer to work with animating over the transform!

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightGreen"
       RenderTransform="{data:CompositeTransform ScaleX=2.5, ScaleY=1, SkewX=-60, Rotation=145}"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
```

Implementation:

```
public class CompositeTransformExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public double CenterX
    {
        get { return _scale.CenterX; }
        set
        {
            _scale.CenterX = value;
            _skew.CenterX = value;
            _rotate.CenterX = value;

        }
    }

    public double CenterY
    {
        get { return _scale.CenterY; }
        set
        {
            _scale.CenterY = value;
            _skew.CenterY = value;
            _rotate.CenterY = value;
        }
    }

    public double ScaleX
    {
        get { return _scale.ScaleX; }
        set { _scale.ScaleX = value; }
    }

    public double ScaleY
    {
        get { return _scale.ScaleY; }
        set { _scale.ScaleY = value; }
    }

    public double SkewX
    {
        get { return _skew.AngleX; }
        set { _skew.AngleX = value; }
    }

    public double SkewY
    {
        get { return _skew.AngleY; }
        set { _skew.AngleY = value; }
    }

    public double Rotation
    {
        get { return _rotate.Angle; }
        set { _rotate.Angle = value; }
    }

    public double TranslateX
    {
        get { return _translate.X; }
        set { _translate.X = value; }
    }

    public double TranslateY
    {
        get { return _translate.Y; }
        set { _translate.Y = value; }
    }

    private ScaleTransform _scale = new ScaleTransform();
    private SkewTransform _skew = new SkewTransform();
    private RotateTransform _rotate = new RotateTransform();
    private TranslateTransform _translate = new TranslateTransform();

    public CompositeTransformExtension()
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var group = new TransformGroup();

        group.Children.Add(_scale);
        group.Children.Add(_skew);
        group.Children.Add(_rotate);
        group.Children.Add(_translate);

        return group;
    }
}
```