# WPF Rotate an Image and align it

Tags: wpf, xaml, rotation, rendertransform

I've an Image component where I want to rotate the source :

```
<Image Name="ImageTarget" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Main.BindedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource ImageSizeConverter}}" />
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding Main.BindedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource ImageSizeConverter}}" />
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

I set the source of `ImageTarget` from the code.

Before the transformation (RenderTransformOrigin and RotateTransform) my window was like :

[image]

But after the rotation :

[image]

So, as you can see, the Width and Height has changed.

So my questions are:

- Why the size has changed ?
- How to align the rotated image on the top left corner (same as before) ?

Thanks

Edit: Size hasn't changed, I have taken the two different screenshots with a different size, and stackoverflow automatically resize them.

Comment: Take a look at [TransformedBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.transformedbitmap.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Transforms were applied after the layout pass. You should use a `LayoutTransform` to perform the transformation before the layout is calculated:

```
<Image Name="ImageTarget" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
<Image.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Main.BindedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource ImageSizeConverter}}" />
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding Main.BindedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource ImageSizeConverter}}" />
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
    </TransformGroup>
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

Comment: Please note that you don't need two ScaleTransforms. You can bind both ScaleX and ScaleY of a single ScaleTransform.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to be relevant for UWP apps. Do you have any idea how to make it work properly? You can see more details in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53176985/997940

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use `CompositeTransform` instead of `RotateTransform` and `ScaleTransform`. Then you can call `Rotate` and `TranslateX`/`TranslateY` inside of the `CompositeTransform` tag to move your object.

In your code dimensions was changed because of `ScaleX`/`ScaleY`!

Comment: Unfortunately, CompositeTransform is not available in WPF : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201675/is-compositetransform-used-only-in-silverlight

Comment: Oh ok, sorry! Did you tried the TransformGroup then?

Comment: no problem :) Novitchi S answer has solved this issue